# JSS connected mode enters experience editor mode

Tags: experience-editor, jss

When I'm working with the local web server `(jss start:connected)` and at the same time I log into the actual instance of Sitecore (dev.test.com) and go to the experience editor. The local version get's stuck in experience editor mode.

The reason seems to be that chrome reads the cookies for the (dev.test.com) URL as well as the cookies for (localhost).

Deleting the sc_mode cookie that says edit or logging out from Sitecore seems to be the only way to fix this problem.

Is this a bug in Sitecore or what am I missing?

Comment: The session is shared. You need to run one in normal and one in incognito. Or use different browsers like Chrome and Firefox or whatever.

Comment: This still feels like a bug in sitecore though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's how domain based cookies work. If you've got cookies saying you're in edit mode on domain.sitecore.local, it's going to render in edit mode whether you're connected or not, because both the connected mode data and the integrated data come from the same domain. You can quickly get out of edit mode by visiting your.sitecore.domain/?sc_mode=normal which is mildly quicker than deleting a cookie, or use incognito mode like @MarkCassidy suggested.